# Base64 encoding not working outside android

Tags: java, android, encoding, base64, android-camera2

Sorry if i am doing something silly. What i was trying to do is capture image from camera2 api in android and after that converting that image to base64 encode below is my code

```
 private String getBase64Image(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 15, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String base64Image = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return base64Image;
}

private void decodeBase64Image(String base64Image) {
    byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(base64Image, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    saveFile(bytes);
}
```

and here how i am capturing image

```
@Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader imageReader) {
            Image image = imageReader.acquireLatestImage();
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte jpegBytes[] = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
            byteBuffer.get(jpegBytes);
            Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jpegBytes, 0, jpegBytes.length);

            String base64Image = getBase64Image(imageBitmap);
            Log.d("mi", "widthpx:" + image.getWidth() + " heightpx:" + image.getHeight());
            Log.d("mi", "Base64Image:" + base64Image);
            decodeBase64Image(base64Image);
            image.close();
        }
    }, null);
```

code above works properly its convert image to base64 encode and later decode it and set on imageview which i can see. Its working fine till here. But problem is that when i use that base64 encode and try with some online base64 string to image converter it does not give me any result. Below is how i am getting base64 encoded string

> 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

*SOLUTION*

As answered from @toble i was not getting full base64Image string in Log.d() so what i did to log full base64Image is as below.

```
   private void logLargeString(String content) {
    if (content.length() > 3000) {
        Log.d("mi", content.substring(0, 3000));
        logLargeString(content.substring(3000));
    } else {
        Log.d("mi", content);
    }
}
```

Hope this may help to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your base64 string contains only the beginning of a jpeg image. Only the first 60 lines of the image contain actual colored pixels.

Make sure to use the complete base64 string and you should be able to see the complete image. You probably used the string logged with:

```
            Log.d("mi", "Base64Image:" + base64Image);
```

The output was probably cropped in logcat.

Comment: I used [this image converter](https://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter).

Comment: thanks @toble.... That was the exact issue... I will update my question how i resolved this problem so that it may be helpful for people in future

Comment: how then copied that base64 string from logcat to paste it another website.